# --git-dir not using the given folder, instead creating a different one with repository name

Tags: git

I want to deploy my repository code to A/B

I want the .git info to be stored in another folder, found at A/B/C

Here is what I'm trying:

git --work-tree=A/B --git-dir=A/B/C clone git@bitbucket:myrepo/is/here

Results:

Repository IS cloned into A/B

.git information is stored in a folder A/X, whereby X is the name of the repository (not A/B/C).

Why is this happening? Why doesn't the .git information go to A/B/C, and why does it create a hidden folder with the title of the repository to hold the git information instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git-clone` doesn't accept the `git-dir` command.  It, like `git-init`, takes the argument for the repository path on the command line.

If you want to specify the location of the working directory separately from the repository, specify the `directory` argument to clone (while continuing to specify `--work-tree`):

```
git --work-tree=worktree clone ssh://repo/url repo
```

This will create a repository directory `repo`, and a worktree named `worktree`.

Note that in your example, you used `A/B` for worktree and `A/B/C` for the repository.  You can do that, but you shouldn't.  If you want the repository beneath the working tree, you should keep the repository named `.git`.  Otherwise, you might have a directory `C` in your working tree, which would then get mixed up between the repository's files and working tree files.  That's very bad.

Now, then, if your command didn't work, why didn't git complain about it?  Well, frankly, it's likely that nobody thought about this interaction.  See, git is implemented in a way that you can specify arguments *to git*, and you can specify arguments to the command (like *git-clone*).  Eg:

```
git --global-arguments command --command-arguments
```

You can see this, for example, with an argument like `--version`, which is a global command, and will run and ignore the command you specify:

```
% git --version push
git version 2.3.2 (Apple Git-55)
```

But if you try to specify that as an argument to push, it will fail:

```
% git push --version
error: unknown option `version'
```

Since `--git-dir` is a global option, so that all commands can take advantage of it, `git-clone` has no choice in whether it can be accepted or not.  (Though it seems like it may be a bug that it silently ignores the argument.)